# react-railsでstyled-componentsをimportするとサーバーサイドレンダリング(prerender: true)が出来ない。

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs

railsでreact-railsを使用しています。
viewファイルにてview helperのreact_componentの引数に`{prerender: true}`を渡した際に問題なくサーバーサイドレンダリングが行われ画面が表示されますが、jsファイルでstyled-componentsをimportすると以下のようなエラーが出ます。

```
Encountered error "#<ExecJS::ProgramError: Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.>" when prerendering hoge with {}
ReactDOMServerRenderer.render ((execjs):56839:21)
```

```
// アプリ/app/views/zukan/species/index.html.slim
= react_component("hoge", {}, { prerender: true })
```

```js
// アプリ/app/javascript/components/hoge.js
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

const hoge = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <p>hogehoge</p>
      <Fuga>fugafuga</Fuga>
    </>
  );
}

const Fuga = styled.div`
  background: red;
`

export default hoge
```

エラー内容からimportの記述の仕方が間違っているかと思いましたが、`{prerender: false}`の場合はstyled-componentsをimportしていても問題なく画面が表示されます。
以下設定ファイルです。

```js
// アプリ/app/javascript/packs/application.js

import Rails from "@rails/ujs"
import Turbolinks from "turbolinks"
import * as ActiveStorage from "@rails/activestorage"
import "channels"

Rails.start()
Turbolinks.start()
ActiveStorage.start()
// Support component names relative to this directory:
var componentRequireContext = require.context("components", true);
var ReactRailsUJS = require("react_ujs");
ReactRailsUJS.useContext(componentRequireContext);
```

```js
// アプリ/app/javascript/packs/server_rendering.js
var componentRequireContext = require.context("components", true);
var ReactRailsUJS = require("react_ujs");
ReactRailsUJS.useContext(componentRequireContext);
```

```yaml
# アプリ/config/webpacker.yml

default: &default
  source_path: app/javascript
  source_entry_path: packs
  public_root_path: public
  public_output_path: packs
  cache_path: tmp/cache/webpacker
  webpack_compile_output: true

  # Additional paths webpack should lookup modules
  # ['app/assets', 'engine/foo/app/assets']
  additional_paths: []

  # Reload manifest.json on all requests so we reload latest compiled packs
  cache_manifest: false

  # Extract and emit a css file
  extract_css: false

  static_assets_extensions:
    - .jpg
    - .jpeg
    - .png
    - .gif
    - .tiff
    - .ico
    - .svg
    - .eot
    - .otf
    - .ttf
    - .woff
    - .woff2

  extensions:
    - .jsx
    - .mjs
    - .js
    - .sass
    - .scss
    - .css
    - .module.sass
    - .module.scss
    - .module.css
    - .png
    - .svg
    - .gif
    - .jpeg
    - .jpg

development:
  <<: *default
  compile: true

  # Reference: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/
  dev_server:
    https: false
    host: localhost
    port: 3035
    public: localhost:3035
    hmr: false
    # Inline should be set to true if using HMR
    inline: true
    overlay: true
    compress: true
    disable_host_check: true
    use_local_ip: false
    quiet: false
    pretty: false
    headers:
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    watch_options:
      ignored: '**/node_modules/**'


test:
  <<: *default
  compile: true

  # Compile test packs to a separate directory
  public_output_path: packs-test

production:
  <<: *default

  # Production depends on precompilation of packs prior to booting for performance.
  compile: false

  # Extract and emit a css file
  extract_css: true

  # Cache manifest.json for performance
  cache_manifest: true
```

バージョンは以下の通りです。

Ruby 2.6.3
Rails 6.0.3.4

どうしたらstyled-componentsを使用してもサーバーサイドレンダリングが行われるでしょうか？ご教示お願いいたします！
また、さらに必要な情報などもあれば教えていただけると幸いです。

Comment: 質問の本質部分とは異なるかもしれませんが，質問のコードだけではstyled-componentsをインポートこそされているもののどこでも参照されていないように見えます(これだけでは実際にはインポートすらされない)

Comment: @hinaloe ご指摘いただきありがとうございます。styled-componentsを参照するように編集いたしました。